# How to create File from Image Url without download Image

Tags: android, image, file, url

How to create **`File`** from Imageurl?

I know How to

> Download Image from Url using AsyncTask

I want to know about how can I create **`File`** object without download Image from url.

I tried like below.

```
File file = new File("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg");
```

I want to use this file in status.setMedia(file)

```
    StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(twitterMessage);
    status.setMedia(file );
    try {
           twitter4j.Status response = twitter.updateStatus(status);
           return response.toString();
    } catch (TwitterException e1) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But no success.

**Please help me about create File direct from imageurl without download Image.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to create File from Imageurl?

You don't. `File` is for local files. A URL is for something that is stored on a server, and particularly in this case, that server is not the device itself, and so the URL does not point to a local file... unless you download a copy of that content *to* a local file.

> I want to use this file in status.setMedia(file)

See if that API offers other parameter types than `File`, like `Uri`, that the library would use to support network-based sources of the media. If not, you have no choice but to download the data and provide a `File` pointing to your local copy.

Comment: That means First I want to download Image from url and create File from that downloaded Image?

Comment: First I download Image bitmap and create file from that bitmap and after posting to twitter I delete file from storage.

Answer (score 0):

you means show the image with a default image,but not really download.
then,when click on it,download it.right?

you can request JSON info from server then store the ImagerUrls into a list.when the user click the imageView ,then you can take out the ImagerUrl and download the image with volley or AsyncTask.

Comment: No no. I don't want that. I want to create File object from url without Download Image from url.